# this.dispose() en Eclipse no funciona

Tags: java, eclipse

Cuando escribo:

```
this.dispose();
```

Usando Eclipse con Windows Builder, no me funciona, no me cierra la ventana actual, que puedo hacer?.

Código:

```
package ventanas;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import datos.Dato_login;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import logicas.Logica_login;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Ventana_login extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7948060398287723741L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txtUsuario;
    private JPasswordField txtContrasena;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Ventana_login frame = new Ventana_login();
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                    // Centrar el Frame en la pantalla
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Ventana_login() {
        setTitle("Sistema Gestor de Eventos v1.0");
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblBienvenidoAlSistema = new JLabel("Bienvenido");
        lblBienvenidoAlSistema.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblBienvenidoAlSistema.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        lblBienvenidoAlSistema.setBounds(10, 11, 424, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblBienvenidoAlSistema);

        JLabel lblUsuario = new JLabel("Usuario");
        lblUsuario.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lblUsuario.setBounds(96, 79, 70, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblUsuario);

        JLabel lblContrasena = new JLabel("Contrase\u00F1a");
        lblContrasena.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lblContrasena.setBounds(96, 109, 70, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblContrasena);

        txtUsuario = new JTextField();
        txtUsuario.setBounds(176, 76, 150, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtUsuario);
        txtUsuario.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnIniciarSesion = new JButton("Iniciar Sesi\u00F3n");
        btnIniciarSesion.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    Dato_login d_lgn = new Dato_login();
                    Logica_login l_lgn = new Logica_login();

                    d_lgn.setUsuario(txtUsuario.getText());
                    char[] contrasenaChar = txtContrasena.getPassword();
                    String contrasenaClean = new String(contrasenaChar);
                    d_lgn.setContrasena(contrasenaClean);

                    Dato_login d_lgn2 = l_lgn.login(d_lgn.getUsuario(), d_lgn.getContrasena());

                    if (Logica_login.resultado) {
                        Ventana_menu v_menu = new Ventana_menu();
                        v_menu.setVisible(true);
                        v_menu.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                        Ventana_menu.lblPerfilActual.setText(d_lgn2.getPerfil());
                        Ventana_menu.lblApellidoActual.setText(d_lgn2.getApellido());
                        Ventana_menu.lblNombreActual.setText(d_lgn2.getNombre());
                        Ventana_menu.lblUsuarioActual.setText(d_lgn2.getUsuario());

                        if (Ventana_menu.lblPerfilActual.getText().equals("Portero")) {
                            Ventana_menu.btnMantenimiento_Eventos.setEnabled(false);
                            Ventana_menu.btnMantenimiento_Invitaciones.setEnabled(false);
                            Ventana_menu.btnMantenimiento_Invitados.setEnabled(false);
                            Ventana_menu.btnMantenimiento_Usuarios.setEnabled(false);
                            Ventana_menu.btnReportes.setEnabled(true);
                        } else {
                            Ventana_menu.btnMantenimiento_Eventos.setEnabled(true);
                            Ventana_menu.btnMantenimiento_Invitaciones.setEnabled(true);
                            Ventana_menu.btnMantenimiento_Invitados.setEnabled(true);
                            Ventana_menu.btnMantenimiento_Usuarios.setEnabled(true);
                            Ventana_menu.btnReportes.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                        // DISPOSE
                        this.dispose();
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "Acceso Denegado", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception:\n" + e, "Error: Ventana_login", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
            }
        });
        btnIniciarSesion.setBounds(176, 163, 150, 30);
        contentPane.add(btnIniciarSesion);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("2016 \u00A9 PUCMM - Programaci\u00F3n I");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 9));
        lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 246, 424, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

        txtContrasena = new JPasswordField();
        txtContrasena.setBounds(176, 106, 150, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtContrasena);

        JCheckBox chckbxMostrarContrasena = new JCheckBox("Mostrar contrase\u00F1a");
        chckbxMostrarContrasena.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (chckbxMostrarContrasena.isSelected()) {
                    txtContrasena.setEchoChar((char)0);
                } else {
                    txtContrasena.setEchoChar('\u2022');
                }
            }
        });
        chckbxMostrarContrasena.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        chckbxMostrarContrasena.setBounds(176, 133, 150, 23);
        contentPane.add(chckbxMostrarContrasena);

        JLabel lblSistemaGestorDe = new JLabel("Sistema Gestor De Eventos");
        lblSistemaGestorDe.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblSistemaGestorDe.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
        lblSistemaGestorDe.setBounds(10, 36, 424, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblSistemaGestorDe);
    }
}
```

Comment: Agrega tu código por favor Robert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede deberse a dos fallos distintos:

#### Fallo usando `this`

Cuando usas `this.dispose()` hay que tener cuidado qué es `this`. Fíjate bien en el ámbito en que lo estás llamando para asegurarte que realmente es lo que quieres cerrar.

#### Fallo con otro elemento

La documentación de Java [(Window.dispose())](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose()) dice que libera todos los recursos propios y sus subcomponentes, pero también dice:

> The Window and its subcomponents can be made displayable again by rebuilding the native resources with a subsequent call to pack or show.

Quiere decir que la ventana puede volver a ser mostrada si "otro elemento" lo hace y lo debe estar haciendo aunque veas que el código sigue avanzando hasta salir del `main`.

#### Solución a lo bruto

Si quieres matar de verdad la aplicación después de llamar a `dispose()` puedes llamar a `System.exit(1)`. Eso cierra la ejecución de la JVM.

Comment: he editado mi post inicial con el codigo, no es largo, porque no me quiere cerrar, a ver si me da una mano.

Comment: El error es por el fallo del this. Estás intentando cerrarlo desde dentro de tu método actionPerformed. Ahí this no es el frame, es el ActionListener anónimo

Comment: y como se llama ese anonimo?, o sea donde esta tu nombre de variable?, o debo agregar otro actionlistener dentro de ese actionperformed?

Comment: Esa clase anónima está bien así, no te hace falta buscarla, no quieres hacer `dispose` sobre ella si no sobre el frame. En vez de poner `this.dispose()` simplemente pon `dispose()` y así llamará al método del frame.

Comment: vale funciona, gracias!!.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Agrega tu código, pero puedes tratar mandar llamarlo de tu instancia JFrame:

```
jframe.dispose();
```

Comment: he editado mi post inicial con el codigo, por que no me quiere cerrar.